# CoreData relationship not consistent (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, relationships

I'm having an issue where I have a set of CoreData objects like so:

organisation > customer > order > ordersku

Where each of those relationships is One-To-Many.

From the ordering screen this works fine for the following:

**print(order.customer.getJSON())** -
(Customer includes the JSON for its containing orders)

```
[
    "id": 300,
    "orders": ({
         customer_id = 300;
         deliverydate = "<null>";
         id = "-681F71DDA4B5413782A6150C10F7A314";
         skus = ({
             code = "CC1";
             id = "-4B5C1EE9DB8745A8963F6167C6DAA4F3";
           },
             code = "CC2";
             id = "-B3FB1A7F13334351AF9D85D9150730A1";
           });
    }),
]
```

However if I attempt the same when stepping one object deeper into the relationships:

**print(order.customer.organisation.customers().first!.getJSON())** -
(Where the organisation only has one customer)

```
[
    "id": 300,
    "orders": (),
]
```

I simply don't get any orders. This then proves problematic when I try to generate JSON for the customer down the line.

These two requests get performed directly after each other meaning the state of the model shouldn't be changing between.

```
let cus1 = order.customer
print("== \(cus1.getJSON())")

let cus2 = order.customer.organisation.customers().first!
print("== \(cus2.getJSON())")

if cus1 == cus2 {
    print("MATCHED")
} else {
    print("UNMATCHED")
}
```

It results in "UNMATCHED", despite the IDs being the same, or conceptually referring to the same and only customer.

And if it helps, below is the code for the customers() method I use on organisation, which simply refers to the relationship rather than trying to retrieve the objects from a context.

```
func customers() -> [Customer] {
    var customers = relatedcustomers.allObjects as! [Customer]

    return customers
}
```

Comment: Are you somehow creating two separate instances of the same customer in your code?  If so it might be safer to use something like `if cus1.objectID = cus2.objectID {}`  assuming they are `NSManagedObjects`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might have created the same customer more than once. You could have added the order to one instance, but not the other one. `first` will just retrieve any one without a defined order from an `NSSet` (for an array this would depend on the sort key).

Second, your call to `customers()` is unfamiliar. In Core Data, you get the `NSSet` of the relationship with `customers`. If you have a custom function in your `NSManagedObject` subclass you might want to rename it to something different than the relationship name.